# Running multiple processes and IPC using python scripts

Tags: python, ssh, ipc, paramiko

I'm working on developing a test automation framework. I need to start three processes(Client, Host adaptor and Host) using python scripts. I'm new to python language.

I have a python script which starts the host adaptor and the host.
While they wait for the client to start, I need to start the client. The client communicates with the host adaptor. 
If I start the client in the same script, I receive the signal SIGPIPE. Hence I moved the code to start Client to another script

If I try to start the client from a different script, there is no communication between the client and the host adaptor.

Script 1 looks like this:

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file('ssh.log')

#Starting process 1- Host
client2 = paramiko.SSHClient()
client2.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client2.connect('10.4.0.65',22, username='FBML7HR', password='mypwd')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client2.exec_command('cd  /var/home/FBML7HR/SrcCode/yyy/xxx/north/test/hostsim/; ./host')

#Starting process 2- Host adatpor

client1 = paramiko.SSHClient()
client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client1.connect('10.4.0.65',22, username='FBML7HR', password='mypwd')
 stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('cd /var/home/FBML7HR/SrcCode/yyy/xxx/north/build/Linux-2.6.18-194.8.1.el5/bin/; export VXNHOME=/home/FBML7HR ;echo $VXNHOME; ./hostadptor')
```

Script2 looks like this:

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file('ssh1.log')

#Starting Client
client3 = paramiko.SSHClient()
client3.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client3.connect('10.4.0.65',22, username='FBML7HR', password='mypwd')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client3.exec_command('cd   /var/home/FBML7HR/SrcCode/yyy/xxx/north/test/vxnclient_mt; ./vxnclient_north_mt 105 19239 105 16889 19239 60000 60000 1 1; ps -ef | grep vxnclient_north_mt')
```

What am I missing to perform inter process communication using these scripts?
Any help would be much appreciated.